# user defined metadata in aws-ios-sdk S3PutObjectRequest

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services

with aws-ios-sdk v1.7.1 I'm running the following code:

```
AmazonS3Client *s3 = [[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithCredentials:uploadToken.credentials];
S3PutObjectRequest *request = [[S3PutObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:uploadPath inBucket:uploadToken.container_name];
request.contentType = contentType;
request.data        = data;
request.delegate    = self;

@try {
    // Put the image data into the specified s3 bucket and object.
    [s3 putObject:request];
}
@catch (AmazonClientException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"exception %@", [exception description]);
}
```

which works fine.

I'm trying to find a way to add my own metadata to be stored with the object in AWS.
Anyone has any insight into this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the method:

```
-(void)addMetadataWithValue:(NSString *)value forKey:(NSString *)aKey;
```

on the request object to add metadata.

```
[request addMetadataWithValue:@"name" value:@"value"];
```